# Altering on container status with Stackdriver and GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I must surely be missing something obvious. GCP provides me with all sorts of visible indications when a container has failed to start. For example:

[image: Failed deployment]

[image: Container Status]

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make it issue an alert when the container status is not OK.

How is it done?

Comment: Hello Sam, can you check if https://stackoverflow.com/a/54034049/12524159 answers your question? there is a good example on how to create alerts based on pod events. If not, specify which kind of events do you want to create an alert and I can help you building it.

Comment: @willrof Thanks for the reply. I think that answer makes sense, but I can't find what log entries I should be looking for for missing minimum availability or CrashLoopBackOff etc.

Answer (score 2):

- > [`CrashLoopBackOff`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting?&_ga=2.52678688.-945193803.1584444246#CrashLoopBackOff) indicates that a container is repeatedly crashing after restarting. A container might crash for many reasons, and checking a Pod's logs might aid in troubleshooting the root cause.

Apart from the error text message `Does not have minimum availability`, there could be other error text messages such as `Failed to pull image`. However, I recommend you to identify error text messages  which are appropriate for your environment. You can check with `kubectl logs <pod_name>` or on Log Viewer.

For your reference, here are explanations for [pod issues](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#workload_issues):

1. **CrashLoopBackOff** means the container was downloaded but failed to run
2. **ImagePullBackOff** means the image was not downloaded
3. **"Does not have minimum availability"** means that there are no resources available on cluster but not specific to a lack of resources. For instance there maybe nodes available but the pod is not scheduleable on them per the deployment.
4. **"Insufficient cpu"** means there is insufficient cpu on the nodes.
5. **"Unschedulable"** indicates that your Pod cannot be scheduled because of insufficient resources or some configuration error.

---

With that in mind, Here is the step-by-step for creating a Log based Metric for later creating an alert based on it.

1. Setup a [Logs-based Metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics#getting_started) using the parameters:

   ```
   resource.type="k8s_pod"
   severity>=WARNING
   unschedulable
   ```

   You can replace the filter to something that is more appropriate for your case.
2. Create a label in the metric that will allow you to identify the pod that was `unschedulable` (or other status). This will also help with grouping when you create the alert for a failing pod.
3. In Stackdriver Monitoring, [create an alert](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui) with the following parameters.

   - Set the resource type to `k8s_pod`
   - Set the metric to the one you created in step 1
   - Set `Group By` to the `pod_name` (also created in step 1)
   - In the advanced aggregation section set the aligner to `sum` and the Alignment Period to `5m` (or what you thinks is more appropriate).
   - Configure the condition triggers `For` to more than 1 minute to prevent the alert from firing over and over. This can also be configured per your requirement.

I hope this information is helpful, If you have any questions let me know in the comments.